# Vuejs Add Table Row Dynamically - Save Row Problem

Tags: vue.js, appendchild

I'm appending `<tr>` elements to my table as long as the `Add Button` is clicked. When the Add Button is clicked, I create 7 `<input type="text">` to type for the respective columns. I also have `Delete` and `Delete All` functionalities and they all work good. Here is my table;

```
<tr v-for="(table, index) in table" :key="index">
              <td>
                <span class="sidebar-icons">unfold_more</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test1" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test2" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test3" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test4" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test5" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test6" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-model="table.test7" placeholder="Test1" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button @click="deleteRow(index)" type="button">Delete</button> 
                <button @click="applyRow()" type="button">Apply</button> 
              </td>
            </tr>
```

And here is my methods;

```
 data(){
      return {
        table: []
      }
    },
    components: {
    methods: {
      deleteAll() {
        this.table = [];
      },
      addRow() {
        this.table.push({
          test1: "",
          test2: "",
          test3: "",
          test4: "",
          test5: "",
          test6: "",
          test7: "",
        });
      },
      deleteRow(index){
        this.table.splice(index, 1);
      },
      applyRow(){
        
      }
    }
```

And here is my question, when I click the add button I trigger the `AddRow()` methods (I didn't put Add and Delete All button here, they are irrelevant to the question.)

When AddRow gets triggered, the inputs are created and I can type things inside of them but as you can see, the `applyRow()` function is empty. What I want to do is, when the Apply button is clicked, I want the texts to display in `<p></p>`, in other words, when the Apply is clicked, I don't want to see any `<input type=text>` anymore. I want them to be seen as paragraphs. I only want to see the inputs when I click the add button to add a new row. How can I create this `applyRow()` method?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to be able to create multiple rows at once ? or just one at a time ?

Comment: I only add one row at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a flag when you add a new row

```
 addRow() {
        this.table.push({
          test1: "",
          test2: "",
          test3: "",
          test4: "",
          test5: "",
          test6: "",
          test7: "",
          applied: false,
        });
      },
```

and your applyRow() method should be like

```
applyRow(index){
       this.table[index].applied = true; 
}
```

and change your template like

```
<tr v-for="(table, index) in table" :key="index">
              <td>
                <span class="sidebar-icons">unfold_more</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test1" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test1</p>
    enter code here
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test2" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test2</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test3" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test3</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test4" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test4</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test5" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test5</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test6" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test6</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input v-if="!table.applied" v-model="table.test7" placeholder="Test1" />
                <p v-else>table.test7</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button @click="deleteRow(index)" type="button">Delete</button> 
                <button v-if="!table.applied" @click="applyRow(index)" type="button">Apply</button> 
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I did pretty much the same thing but I forgot putting the index inside of the applyRow function and it was showing and hiding every row. Now it's perfect. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What should I do if I want to hide Apply Button after its clicked? I mean, when I fill all 7 inputs I click Apply and the row is inserted. At that point, I don't need Apply button to be seen.

Comment: add a v-if for that button also

Comment: Okay one final question :) I have also a draggable function in my table so I can drag rows when I want them above or below etc... So If I put the second row above, the first one's ID will be 2, and the second row's will be 1. How do I give the ID information automatically. The first added row is 1, the second row is 2 etc. I mean, let's prevent user to type the ID and give it in advance. How do I do that?

Comment: add  :id="index" to your <tr></tr>

Comment: I removed the ID input from the first column of the added row. I put <p v-if="table.applied">{{ index+1 }}</p> and now it adds the ID starting from 1. But when I drag the second row above the fist row, I should change the index also. That is my problem now.

Comment: I didnt get you, did you see my prev comment...did you try it ..did it work?

Comment: It didn't work but I managed to do it. I did the things that I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: then define a computed property that returns the current index of that element and assign it to the id. Also make sure that we you reorder items the array should also get reordered